Would an Antimagic Field become larger if the target is larger?
For example, if someone takes space 30*30 ft. casts Antimagic Field, would the total radius of the AMF become larger than someone takes space 5*5 ft.?
Or would that creature not showing any effect externally other than becoming immune to all magical effects because it is the only one within (kind of) the AMF? Since if the center point of the AMF is the center of the creature, it can't go over the creature's space.
